# How to hide blocks from administrator?

Tags: 8, blocks

I need to hide some blocks from priviledged user so he won't be able to attach them to regions via the Block layout. What is the proper way of doing this?

Comment: Do you both have the same permissions? If so, you won't be able to hide them from him, as they will hide from you as well. If he is a different rank, you can make it so he can't use them in the permissions area of the dashboard.

Comment: I should be more clear - it's not about "permissions". I'm making a distribution and I don't want admin to see some blocks(at all). The only thing that comes to mind is extending the block plugin manager but I don't like that approach.
I could overwrite the access controller for the Block entity but that would apply only to "instances" not plugins(blocks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please open a feature request in the core queue for `'no ui'` blocks. This currently does not exist but it's an interesting (and probably necessary one).

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/2273433